# Can complements of infinite disjoint sets be finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume the set $X$ is infinite (has an infinite amount of elements). Intuitively, it seems to me that two infinite, disjoint, sets $A,B \in X$ cannot have complements that are both finite, i.e. $A^c$ and $B^c$ cannot both be finite. Is this true? How can I show it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

The complement of $A$ will contain $B$ as a subset (and vice versa).

Comment: Ah, of course! :)